# "Incorrect MySQL client library version"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, homebrew

I'm getting the following error when running `rake assets:precompile`

`Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.6.10 but the client library is 5.5.12.`

MySQL is installed using Homebrew and is version 5.6.10. I can connect to the database on 127.0.0.1 locally.

I've tried the following with no luck:

`ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

It seems that advice is for folks whose "client library" is newer than the one the Gem was compiled for. My issue is the opposite. Can't figure out where the 5.5.12 is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you running? You need to know the version of libmysqlclient-dev installed. For instance, in debian/ubuntu/mint, you get the version by the output of: dpkg -l | grep libmysqlclient-dev  // So you will probably need to upgrade this package

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same issue and no luck so far.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
gem uninstall mysql
gem uninstall mysql2
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This may need a config argument prior to `bundle install`, e.g. bundle config mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.0.10/bin/mysql_config (see https://wincent.com/wiki/Force_re-installing_the_MySQL_gem)