# Incorrect MySQL client library version in RHEL server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rhel7

I have installed mysql in a `RHEL 7` server. I have deployed my rails code in the same. When I run my migration I get the following error. I have installed `mysql` and I want the connection to be done to mysql and `not mariadb`.

```
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! 
This gem was compiled for 5.5.37-MariaDB but the client library is 5.6.20.
```

What should I do get this fixed?

EDIT:

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: blah_development
```

Comment: Maybe upgrade the version of DB client?
AFAIK the latest version of MariaDB client library is 5.7.4

Comment: @EugeneTkachenko, I have installed mysql and I want the connection to be done to mysql and not mariadb.

Comment: Got you.
What you have into the config/database.yml?

Comment: @EugeneTkachenko, please refer edit.

Comment: I think it will helps you [Link on answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141985/ruby-mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library-version)